# How transfrom numeric date to date format

Tags: r

I have a date '2020-01-01', which is transformed to numeric, Thereafter, I want to transform date numeric variable to date variable. How can I do it?

```
a<-'2020-01-01'
a<-as.numeric(as.Date(a, '%Y-%m-%d'))


#not working
as.Date(a, '%Y%m%d')
format(a, '%Y%m%d')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set `origin`:

```
as.Date(a, origin="1970-01-01")
#[1] "2020-01-01"
```

In `?Date`: *Dates are represented as the number of days since 1970-01-01, ...*.

Answer (score 1):

Using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
as_date(a, origin = '1970-01-01')
#[1] "2020-01-01"
```